# Convert ternary conditional operators into if else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple minified jQuery code and trying to convert it to if else statement. I am getting "Can't find variable: i" error

Here is the code:

```
var c = slider.activeIndex;

0 === c ? (slider.slideTo("1"), $(this).removeClass("active"), $("html").hasClass("touch") || $(".slider-nav").show(), i = null) : (slider.slideTo("0"), $(this).addClass("active"), $(i).removeClass("active"), $(".slider-nav").hide(), i = $(this))
```

I have tried that:

```
if (c === 0) {
    slider.slideTo("1");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $("html").hasClass("touch") || $(".slider-nav").show();
    i = null;
} else {
    slider.slideTo("0");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(i).removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-nav").hide();
    i = $(this);
}
```

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: I am not sure if I converted it to properly actually. I am getting undefined variable i error

Comment: The two codes seem to be identical. If one does give an error, the other will also. You're getting the error because i is not defined, yes. It should be defined before this piece of code. The real error is before this somewhere (you should define i)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply initialize your "i" in the outside scope by doing this:

`var i, c = slider.activeIndex; //and then your code`.

Comment: It'll be an error in non-strict mode too, assuming `i` is truly not declared, and `c !== 0`.